# How do I get String values on listview from the ArrayList<String[]>?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

Hi I had asked before how do I update listview and got suggestion to make use of ArrayAdapter.I follow the thing now the issue is about it's updating listviews but not with expected values some object .

My code is like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM BOOKMARKS ", null);
        //if any contact found moveToFirst of that contacts or points to 1st email 
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        //checking columns exhist or not
        if (cursor.getInt(0) > 0)
        {
            //get all the contacts from table 'BOOKMARKS'
            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM BOOKMARKS", null);
            //get the index of mentiond and required columns 
            ID = c.getColumnIndex("ID");
            booktitl = c.getColumnIndex("Booktiltle");

            audiotime=c.getColumnIndex("BookmarkTime");

            // Check result.
            c.moveToFirst();
            if (c != null) 
            {
                // Loop through all Results
                do 
                {
                    cont = new String[3];
                    cont[0] = Integer.toString(c.getInt(ID));
                    cont[1] = c.getString(booktitl);
                    cont[2] = c.getString(audiotime);
                    audiobooks.add(cont);

                }
                while(c.moveToNext());

c.close();
                db.close();//close db resources 


                ArrayAdapter<String[]> arrayAdapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(this,  R.layout.row3, R.id.itemr1,audiobooks);
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
```

How do i get the string value on listview?Actually the values fetching from database and storing into Arraylist.At present I am displaying some object value on listview but I want to display content that "audiobooks" holds. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: have a look at this great indepth tutorial on ListView and ListActivities: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't give the `ArrayAdapter` the type `String[]`, because you're giving it a `List` called audiobooks.

Also, I'm not sure if the standard `ArrayAdapter` can handle a datatype `List<String[]>`. It might not work. You would have to make your own implementation of the `ArrayAdapter` by extending it, if it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to populate a ListView with data from each row from your database. You must create a new class of type Audiobook with the member variables corresponding with database row. Then create a layout in your res/layouts folder that must show your object's data. Create a new class extending  ArrayAdapter class, in which you inflate views with created layout and populate listview with childs. Then in your main you set the new adapter to the list.

The ArrayAdapter should look like this:

```
public class AudiobookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Audiobook> {
     //  constructor

     //  here you populate each view and put it in listview
     public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    }
}
```

This is a start line, you should read more about extending arrayadapters and custom ListViews.

Comment: Ya Exactly you are correct @Emil Pana I want to populate data from each row of  from database and display it on listview.

Comment: Please keep us to date to your problems, if you need anything or don't understand please post here.